# Create a dataframe of combinations of data with proper labels in R

Tags: r, combinations

I am trying to create a data frame that pulls combinations of values from a data frame, and applies a function on the data, and finally assigning the label of the combinations as identifiers in the data frame.

To create a simple mockup of the data:

```
A = (1:20)
B = seq(1, 40, 2)
```

To create a mockup of each identifier:

```
L = c("q", "r", "q", "p", "q", "p", "r", "r", "r", "r", "r", "r", "r", "r", "o", "p", "q", "r", "r", "q")
```

The mockup data frame is then created with:

```
dat.example = data.frame(A, B, L)
```

Here, the data in each row is subtracted by the data from the previous row, with all possible combinations.

```
diffA = combn(dat.example$A, 2, FUN = diff)
diffB = combn(dat.example$B, 2, FUN = diff)
```

After all possible combination of differences within columns `A` and `B` are calculated, a function is applied on the generated output.

```
calc.diff = sqrt((diffA^2) + (diffB^2))
```

Now comes the tricky part, where I pull out the identifiers for the combinations.

```
(L.list = combn(dat.example$L, 2, simplify = F))

L.list.1 = sapply(L.list, "[[", 1)
L.list.2 = sapply(L.list, "[[", 2)

L.dat = data.frame(
  X = L.list.1,
  Y = L.list.2
)

L.dat$comp = with(
  L.dat,
  interaction(X, Y, sep = "_")
)
```

And combine them into a master dataset

```
master = data.frame(
  calc.diff,
  L.dat$comp
)
```

Is there a simpler way to perform this that I am missing?

Update: I just realised the labels I created in this fashion is duplicated, as `p_q` is equivalent to `q_r` as only the magnitude of the value matters after the `calc.dist` function. Therefore, this question still needs a better answer. My present solution is to simply substitute each occurrence with it's twin in the dataset, but this becomes substantially difficult the more labels there are.

Update 2: I have solved the issue of a pure R solution to properly assigning unique combination of labels to the dataset. Below, I shall paste the entire code for generating the above dataset, and assigning the right labels. Improvements are of course welcomed.

```
A = (1:20)
B = seq(1, 40, 2)
L = c("q", "r", "q", "p", "q", "p", "r", "r", "r", "r", "r", "r", "r", "r", "o", "p", "q", "r", "r", "q")
dat.example = data.frame(A, B, L)
diffA = combn(dat.example$A, 2, FUN = diff)
diffB = combn(dat.example$B, 2, FUN = diff)
calc.diff = sqrt((diffA^2) + (diffB^2))

L.dat.comp <- combn(dat.example$L, 2, paste0, collapse = "_", simplify=F)
master <- data.frame(
  calc.diff,
  id = unlist(L.dat.comp))
```

Function to help with combinations

```
expand.grid.unique <- function(x, y, include.equals=FALSE)
{
  x <- unique(x)

  y <- unique(y)

  g <- function(i)
  {
    z <- setdiff(y, x[seq_len(i-include.equals)])

    if(length(z)) cbind(x[i], z, deparse.level=0)
  }

  do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(x), g))
}
```

Create dataframe with unique combinations of id labels.

```
dat.combo =
as.data.frame(
  expand.grid.unique(L, L, include.equals = T)
)

dat.combo$c1 = with(dat.combo, interaction(V1, V2, sep = "_"))
dat.combo$c2 = with(dat.combo, interaction(V2, V1, sep = "_"))

master$id2 = master$id
```

Where ids match dat.combo$c2, replace with dat.com$c1

```
master$id2[] = setNames(dat.combo$c1,
                        dat.combo$c2)[as.character(
                          unlist(
                            master$id2
                            )
                          )
                          ]
```

Where NAs are present in id2, replace with values in id

```
master$id2[is.na(master$id2)] = master$id[is.na(master$id2)]
```

Comment: I suspect you are looking for `expand.grid`

Comment: You could try `L.dat.comp <-  combn(dat.example$L, 2, paste0, collapse = "_")`

Comment: @Jay, works when you add `simplify=F`.

Comment: @Jay. Thanks for the insight. What does paste0 do in the code?

Comment: @Rewarp, its the function called by `combn` to paste the two identifiers together with an `_` between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Jay's comement for the "tricky part":

```
L.dat.comp <- combn(dat.example$L, 2, paste0, collapse = "_", simplify=F)
master <- data.frame(cbind(calc.diff,unlist(L.dat.comp)))
```

So the whole thing looks like:

```
A = (1:20)
B = seq(1, 40, 2)
L = c("q", "r", "q", "p", "q", "p", "r", "r", "r", "r", "r", "r", "r", "r", "o", "p", "q", "r", "r", "q")
dat.example = data.frame(A, B, L)
diffA = combn(dat.example$A, 2, FUN = diff)
diffB = combn(dat.example$B, 2, FUN = diff)
calc.diff = sqrt((diffA^2) + (diffB^2))
L.dat.comp <- combn(dat.example$L, 2, paste0, collapse = "_", simplify=F)
master <- data.frame(cbind(calc.diff,unlist(L.dat.comp)))
```

Comment: I just realised that the combination of labels that I described needs to go through a further process to eliminate duplicates, since only the magnitude of the data remains, `p_q` is the same as `q_r`. What would be a quick way to standardise all the combinations?

Comment: Do you want to retain both labels or remove duplicate values for the `calc.diff` column?

Comment: The values in calc.diff need to remain, because they are distinct. It's the labels that need to be arrange such that `p_q` and `q_p` are equivalent. Perhaps an alphabetically reordering in the `combn()` function? But I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: I have figured out a solution. But it is a bit messy.